# How to prevent struct instantiation in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there a way in Rust to make a struct only instantiable via it's static method (for example `fn new(...) -> Self`) and not with struct instantiation?

ie:

```
let s = Box::new(MyStruct::new());  // OK

let s = Box::new(MyStruct{...}); // NOT ok - compile time error
```

Is this a reasonable thing to do?
for a struct that will always be passed out of the method that creates it or attached to another owner.

Ie: for an allocated message placed in a queue

Comment: Make the contents private, so the struct can't be literally instantiated out of its crate. Or have an inner type which is private, such that uses of the outer struct are unable to access or instantiate it, thus they have no way of instantiating the outer struct themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent *struct instantiation* by placing it in module which contents are private to the caller and doing one of three things (all of them come down to including private field). Note that preventing struct instantiation will also prevent you from *struct matching* (and structural destruction).

1. Your struct already has private field. You don't have to do anything.

   ```rust
   mod private {
       pub struct Foo {
           pub x: i32,
           pub y: i32,
           z: i32,
       }

       impl Foo {
           pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
               Self { x, y, z: x + y }
           }
       }
   }

   fn foo() {
       let _ = private::Foo::new(1, 2);
       // ERROR: field `z` of struct `Foo` is private
       // let _ = private::Foo{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};
   }
   ```
2. If your struct has only public fields you can add a *zero sized type* private field. This has zero runtime cost, since compiler will remove this field completely. `()` or [`PhantomData<()>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) are often used to do this.

   ```rust
   mod private {
       use std::marker::PhantomData;

       pub struct Foo {
           pub x: i32,
           pub y: i32,
           _phantom: PhantomData<()>,
       }

       impl Foo {
           pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
               Self {
                   x,
                   y,
                   _phantom: PhantomData,
               }
           }
       }
   }

   fn foo() {
       let _ = private::Foo::new(1, 2);
       // ERROR: field `_phantom` of struct `Foo` is private
       // let _ = private::Foo{x: 1, y: 2, _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData};
   }
   ```
3. If you want to prevent this behavior **only for other crates** you can mark your struct as [`#[non_exhaustive]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html#the-non_exhaustive-attribute). This indicates that new fields may be added to the struct, thus preventing other crates from directly naming *all* fields during struct instantiation.

   ```rust
   mod private {
       #[non_exhaustive]
       pub struct Foo {
           pub x: i32,
           pub y: i32,
       }

       impl Foo {
           pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
               Self {
                   x,
                   y,
               }
           }
       }
   }

   fn foo() {
       let _ = private::Foo::new(1, 2);
       // This will be error when used in **another** crate
       // let _ = private::Foo{x: 1, y: 2};
   }
   ```

Comment: For (3), it's also possible to mark field as `pub(crate)`.

Comment: IK will see what this does.  I DO want library users to use fn new to instantiate it but NOT to put it on the stack.  I'm not sure this will allow that.

Comment: @peterk struct instantiatnion has **nothing** to do with in which place in the memory the struct will reside in. `Box::new(MyStruct::new())` and `Box::new(MyStruct{...})` will both create values on the heap.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze. not exactly true.  One will initialize the data ONCE in fn new - the other will initialize it on the stack as an argument to Box with the {} initializer, then move/copy the stack argument to Box into a new heap buffer and drop the stack argument.  This only works with fully copyable structs.  It is a different initialization pathway.